# How to get Primary key value of each record for the foreign key column in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables in my project (User, Cases and Details). I have set up the relationships in the model like following:

- A user can file many cases.
- A case can have only one detail.
- A user can have many details. (Since he can file many cases)

Now, the users can file cases and only the admin can enter the details for each case of the user. What I want is to store the user_id of the corresponding user with the detail of that particular case. In other words, retrieve the ID from user table for that particular case. Here are the codes:

CaseController.php

```
public function storedetail(Request $req, User $user, $id) 
{   
    
    $detail = new Detail;
    $detail->lawyerName = $req->input('lawyerName');
    $detail->event = $req->input('proc_type');
    $detail->room = $req->input('room');
    $detail->eventDate = $req->input('date');
    //$detail->case_id = $id;       
    $detail->user_id = $req->user()->id; 
    $user->details()->save($detail);    
    $data = Cases::find($id);
    $data->details()->save($detail); 


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

(I have passed the case_id from a blade view via URL route)

User.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'is_admin',
];

public function cases()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cases::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Detail::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Cases.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User::class');
    
}

public function details()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Detail::class, 'case_id', 'id'); 
}
```

Detail.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User::class', 'user_id');        
     
}

public function cases()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Cases::class', 'case_id');
}
```

[These are my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N34Ui.jpg)

Comment: How the user_id is belongs to detail table?

Comment: What have you tried already? What went wrong?

Comment: @SachinKumar Its a foreign key to the User table.

Comment: @Chilion I tried the code above but the user_id column stays NULL.

Comment: Can you please highlight the error lins in your question because as per my understanding you are using request ()-> user id as user_id

Comment: You might be able to use a [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) relationship.

Comment: @SachinKumar I am trying to assign the ID from User table to the user_id in the details table which is the foreign key. There is no error thrown by laravel but the user_id stays NULL.

Comment: @Thomas Can you elaborate the changes a bit please?

Comment: It means when you try to save the details of a user then the user_id saved as NULL. If so please show the fillable property of the details table(if any) or specify the 'id' in the user function of the detail.php

Comment: There is no fillable property in details model. Also, I have changed the function to return $this->belongsTo('User::class', 'user_id', 'id)
Still, it stays NULL.